# Auto scroll of edittext while clicking the next button in keypad in android

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollbar, scrollview

I have an 10 `edittexts` in `scrollview`. while 1st `edittext` focused it shows like below image.

[image]

while click to next it shows like this.[image]

but i need `edittext` scrolls automatically like below image
[image]

please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 5):

Add **android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"** to your activity tag in the **AndroidManifest.xml**.
It will automatically adjust the scroll of screen layout accordingly and will not disturb the UI. Try It.!

Comment: it scrolling my hole layout i need to hide before `edittext` and next `edittext` want show

Comment: Ok.So you should keep all edit text in a scroll view and do some hit and try to set the proper height and width of ScrollView.

Comment: than make some changes programmatically. You will have check that whenever particular edit text gets focus than scrollview should scroll up to certain pixels.

Answer (score 2):

this one worked for me.
put all the edittext and buttons in scrollview and write this code

```
ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
                scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
                findViewById(R.id.edittext).requestFocus();
```